# HM Revenue & Customs - Tax man Annual Tax Summary 2015-16 Scam

Tags: authentication

Received a letter purporting to be from HMRC - all the info was wrong. Personal details doesn't have that page were missing, Figures were massive and scary.
It wanted me to go online to a gov.uk/ website if anything needed updating.

BUT genuine HMRC website doesn't have that page.

Any one else had something similar?

Comment: You got a fake letter. Dump it in the trash bin. I don't see an issue here that needs to be solved.